# Where do I place clearTimeOut?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying the following

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    if ("comboFilters[Agencies]" in partDic) {
        var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
        $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }

    if ("comboFilters[Clients]" in partDic) {
        var cl = partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1);
        $('.Client .dropdown-toggle').html(cl).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }

    if ("comboFilters[Years]" in partDic) {
        var yr = partDic["comboFilters[Years]"].substring(1).slice(1);
        $('.Year .dropdown-toggle').html(yr).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: quetsion updated, I am not sure where the clear should be placed

Comment: Also, the tag is wrong. clearTimeout is not specific to jquery.

Comment: is it javascript: I thought was jQuery ?

Comment: Why clear the timeout after the first execution??

Comment: the question updated asks exactly that, where do I place cleartimeOut?

Comment: `setTimeout` only fires once, so this code is pointless as shown. Did you mean to use `setInterval` *and* `clearInterval`?

Comment: What is clearly missing here is a description of *what you actually want to do*. The code is valid as is, though does not really make sense.

Comment: The answer was given by @TrueBlueAussie - I've just learned that clearTimeOut is for setInterval. Thanks

Comment: Can you give some detail about when you want the timeout to stop, without that there is no way of saying where to put it

Comment: @rob.m no - `clearInterval` is for `setInterval`.

Comment: guys @TrueBlueAussie cleared my wrong idea about the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only makes sense in the scope of a repeated timer. For that use `setInterval` and the matching `clearInterval`:

```
var timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
    if ("comboFilters[Agencies]" in partDic) {
        var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
        $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }

    if ("comboFilters[Clients]" in partDic) {
        var cl = partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1);
        $('.Client .dropdown-toggle').html(cl).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }

    if ("comboFilters[Years]" in partDic) {
        var yr = partDic["comboFilters[Years]"].substring(1).slice(1);
        $('.Year .dropdown-toggle').html(yr).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }
    clearInterval(timeoutId);
}, 1000);
```

Obviously you would only call `clearInterval` under specific circumstances (otherwise a single `setTimeout` would do the same job).

e.g.

```
    if ($hit + fan == "hit"){
        clearInterval(timeoutId);   // stop further calls occurring
    }
```

Just to clarify. If you only want to run it once, just call `setTimeout` and do not worry about the return value or `clearTimeout`

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ("comboFilters[Agencies]" in partDic) {
        var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
        $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }

    if ("comboFilters[Clients]" in partDic) {
        var cl = partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1);
        $('.Client .dropdown-toggle').html(cl).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }

    if ("comboFilters[Years]" in partDic) {
        var yr = partDic["comboFilters[Years]"].substring(1).slice(1);
        $('.Year .dropdown-toggle').html(yr).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }
}, 1000);
```

This one is a standard "please run this code after 1 second" pattern.

Comment: ok got it. Thanks for clearing things up

Comment: When you call `clearInterval()` after the first execution of `setInterval()`, isn't that an indicator, that you actually want to use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: yes exactly, and from what you told me if I do, I don't need a clear since it only fires once